# represent $x^3 +2x$ as power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

Well it is pretty wierd for me to see this question, the function already is power series isn't it?
Am I missing the purpose of the excersize?

Comment: Useful to think about if the center isn't $0$, but yeah, there's not too much here.

Comment: The power series of a polynomial is the polynomial itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A power series is an infinite series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$. If for some function $f$ and some set $D$, 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n,\quad x\in D
$$
we say that the RHS is the power series of $f$ **at** $x_0$.

When $f$ is a polynomial function of the form $f(x)=b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_mx^m$, its power series **at** $x_0=0$ is $f$ itself.

In general, you will need to find the coefficients $a_n$ when $x_0\ne 0$. But Taylor's theorem tells you that it has something to do with $f^{(n)}(x_0)$.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused how to represent it as infine series, I can derivative $f(x)$ just 3 times

Comment: @Sagigever: you can differentiate, for instance, the function $g(x)=x^2$ infinitely many times: $g'(x_0)=2x_0$, $g''(x_0)=2$, $g'''(x_0)=0$, $g^{(4)}(x_0)=0$, $g^{(5)}(x_0)=0$,... Note that in the infinite series, the coefficients are allowed to be zero.

Comment: Ok, so I did the way you suggested, but is it possible to write it in $\Sigma$ notation? I can't think how to write the general expressesion

Comment: @Sagigever: Sure. Again, take the example $g(x)=x^2$. Let's say you want to write the power series at $x_0=1$. So you want the coefficients of the infinite series $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n$. So what you have is $a_0=g(1)=1$, $a_1=2x_0=2$, $a_2=\frac{g''(x_0)}{2!}=\frac{2}{2}=1$, $a_3=0$, $a_4=0$,... So $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n=1+2(x-1)+(x-1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the derivatives of $x^3+2x$ gives the general power series representation about $x=a$ as
$$a^3+2a+(3a^2+2)(x-a)+3a(x-a)^2+(x-a)^3$$

Comment: so it will not be infinite series?

Comment: @Sagigever No because there shouldn't be any terms of degree $4$ or higher. Technically it's an infinite series with loads of zero terms because the derivatives of $f(x)$ are all zero for more than three derivatives.